# Multiline UL Slider?

Tags: jquery, slider, html-lists, multiline

Here's what I need to do:

I need to be able to allow for some list items (they'll be available tags for an article) to display inline-block within a fixed area. There will be many of these list items and I need them to wrap up to 3 lines tall, but that's it. After that, I need some way of limiting these so they do not knock down to a fourth line, and instead have some sort of jQuery slider so I can scroll to the right and find more tags.

These tags will be pulled from the server, and will not be hardcoded, so I don't think I can create separate lists. Furthermore, each tag will be a variable width.

I'm a bit stuck and not sure if this is even a possible execution. Any pointers in the right direction are appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you provide some sample HTML. What is contained within the list item? Would an [accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) work better?

Comment: I don't have any HTML really, because I'm not sure how to execute it. It's just an unordered list right now. My only thought would be to make a slider where I'd have separate ULs, where each would have it's own slider section.But as I said this data is being pulled from a database and each li will have a variable width. Each list item is just a word, a "tag" for an article. Accordion wouldn't work, because I never would actually want to show ALL available tags, as there could very many.

Comment: Hmm, well, I am having difficulty picturing what you are trying to accomplish. Do you have a mockup, drawing or even a demo of how you want the tags to look?

Comment: Imagine something like this: [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/707414/tags-example.html) The tag list would build from top left line-by-line. But only for 3 rows or the height of this container. Then, by clicking the arrow, you could slide and see more. Keep in mind these are coming from the server -- so I can't think of a good way to split them up for each slider page.

Comment: I also want to add I could simply make it a scrollable div, but this needs to be functional for touch screen devices as well. And scrolling divs on a touch screen is sort of a pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, ok now that I have a general idea of what you wanted, I put together [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/nhZCG/), but the major difference is that it scrolls up and down instead of right to left.

I think a vertical slider works best because the width of the tags is so variable. That and it made coding a lot easier ;)

CSS

```
h2 {
  font-size:.8em;
  margin:0 5px 10px;
}

#wrap {
  padding:20px;
  background:#DDD;
  height:170px;
  width:680px;
}

#up, #down {
  float: right;
  line-height: 3em;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

#down {
  clear: right;
  margin-top: 4em;
}

#up a, #down a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#FFF;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-family:serif;
  font-size:2em;
  display:block;
}

#up a:hover, #down a:hover {
  color: #999;
}

#window {
  width: 90%;
  height: 9em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
  padding:0;
  margin:0 45px 0 0;
}

ul li {
  padding:10px;
  float:left;
  margin:5px;
  background:#777;
  list-style-type:none;
  color:#FFF;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="up" class="disabled"><a href="#">&#9650;</a></div>
  <div id="down"><a href="#">&#9660;</a></div>
  <h2>Available Tags</h2>
  <div id="window">
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>dolor sit amet</li>
      <li>consectetur</li>
      <li>adipiscing elit</li>
      <li>Pellentesque</li>
      <li>pellentesque justo</li>
      <li>Sed in rutrum lectus</li>
      <li>Vivamus lorem dui</li>
      <li>auctor vitae</li>
      <li>suscipit id</li>
      <li>mollis tempus tellus</li>
      <li>Nullam in turpis sem</li>
      <li>Nulla molestie</li>
      <li>fermentum dictum</li>
      <li>Donec arcu lacus</li>
      <li>lacinia a pretium in</li>
      <li>bibendum eget felis</li>
      <li>Praesent gravida sapien mi</li>
      <li>Mauris purus justo</li>
      <li>vestibulum et volutpat non</li>
      <li>condimentum sit amet est</li>
      <li>Aenean non augue</li>
      <li>tellus rutrum commodo</li>
      <li>Duis malesuada</li>
      <li>tristique diam nec pharetra</li>
      <li>Praesent a facilisis dolor</li>
      <li>Praesent eget orci</li>
      <li>id nisl interdum consectetur</li>
      <li>Quisque ultrices hendrerit risus</li>
      <li>aliquam gravida dolor laoreet sed</li>
      <li>Pellentesque tristique</li>
      <li>commodo eros ac vestibulum</li>
      <li>Curabitur ipsum dui</li>
      <li>lacinia vitae hendrerit et</li>
      <li>luctus in eros</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
  var delay = 500,
  t, win= $('#window'),
  up = $('#up'),
  down = $('#down'),
  winH = win.height() + 10, // 10 = top + bottom margin of li
  bottom = win[0].scrollHeight - winH;

  up
  .click(function(){
    t = win.scrollTop();
    if (t - winH <= 0) {
      t = 0;
      $(this).addClass('disabled').fadeTo(delay, 0);
    } else if (down.hasClass('disabled')) {
      down.removeClass('disabled').fadeTo(delay, 1);
    }
    win.animate({ scrollTop: t - winH}, delay);
  })
  .addClass('disabled')
  .fadeTo(delay, 0);

  down.click(function(){
    var t = win.scrollTop();
    if (t + winH >= bottom) {
      t = bottom;
      down.addClass('disabled').fadeTo(delay, 0);
    } else if (up.hasClass('disabled')) {
      up.removeClass('disabled').fadeTo(delay, 1);
    }
    win.animate({ scrollTop: t + winH}, delay);
  });

});
```

Comment: For the result, aren't you much better off with using native OS widgets and simply putting `overflow:auto` on a div limited to three lines tall?

Comment: @Phrogz Sure that would work too, but I was working from the example html page provided. The OP is free to use whatever :)

Comment: This is perfect! I never thought about doing it up and down, but I don't think it should be a problem this way. Thanks so much. @Phrogz -- can't use scroll because this needs to work seamlessly on touch screen as well. Thanks again fudgey!

Comment: @Mottie : why is the 45px margin-right needed for the ul? It leaves a huge gap in the layout between list items and 'scrollbar'

Comment: Hi @AtroX, it's been so long since I looked at this... I think it was there to leave room for the up and down arrow. I removed it in that demo and I didn't notice any difference. So, it's probably okay to set it to zero.

Comment: @Mottie : what could be the problem in this situation: [link](http://bflydesign.no-ip.org:9876/vandaele/galerij.php) ?

Comment: I think it's the `#window ul li` padding set to `9px`.